# View images stored in the SQL Server in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, sql-server, image, crystal-reports

In my database I have a table that contains an image column.

This column type is `text`.

When saving images in a database that would convert to text.

My code is:

```
Image selectedImage = Image.FromFile(openFileDialog.FileName);

MemoryStream tmpStream = new MemoryStream();
selectedImage.Save(tmpStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg); // change to other format

tmpStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

Byte[] BytesOfImage = tmpStream.ToArray();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < BytesOfImage.Length - 1; i++)
{
    sb.Append(BytesOfImage[i] + ",");
}

sb.Append(BytesOfImage[BytesOfImage.Length - 1]);

sb.ToString(); // sb.ToString() ==> Save to sql server
```

And then convert the string to a photo, I use the following code:

```
String[] split = strImage.Split(',');
Byte[] bytes = new Byte[split.Length];

Byte b;
for (int i = 0; i < split.Length; i++)
{
    Byte.TryParse(split[i], out b);
    bytes[i] = b;
}

MemoryStream tmpStream = new MemoryStream();

tmpStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
tmpStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

Image img = Image.FromStream(tmpStream);
```

Now I want in my report will display the image but the image path does not exist because the image is stored in the database!

How do I view the images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about `Crystal Reporting` but to `ReportViewer` I'm able to pass parameters, those takes only string or string[] so you need to pass in one of these forms.

OR save your image as temporary file and just load it into `pictureBox`.

```
pictureBox1.Load("c:\\temp\\kitten.jpg");
```

OR follow this guide

http://morecoding.wordpress.com/2012/08/07/passing-mages-crystalreport-runtime/

Comment: how can i show image into my report by Image variable?(i have not browse of image)

Comment: I'm sorry, I have never been working with `CrystalReport` I only suggested the algorithms that I'm sure can be used to get what you want.

Comment: @javadaskari if this has been solution for your question please mark it as an answer so other with similar solution would find how to solve this issue. Otherwise please explain your problem so I could help.